# getting an error message: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote this code to calculate the pressure, but I'm getting an error message says "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'
why I'm getting it? how can I fix it?

import numpy as np
# create Q vector
q1=0
q4=5064
list=[q1,0,0,q4]
Q=np.array(list)

```
# Create Act matrix
Act= 8
Act_arr=np.array([Act,Act,Act,Act])
Act_diag = np.diag(Act_arr)
       
# Create J matrix
j1=0
j4=5.064
array = np.array([j1,0,0,j4])
J = np.diag(array)
        
# Create T matrix:
Tr= 2.532
def tridiag(a, b, c, k1=-1, k2=0, k3=1):
    return np.diag(a, k1) + np.diag(b, k2) + np.diag(c, k3)

a = [-Tr, -Tr, -Tr]; b = [Tr, 2*Tr, 2*Tr, Tr]; c = [-Tr, -Tr, -Tr]
T_tr = tridiag(a, b, c) 
dx=1
dt=5
x=np.arange(0,4, dx)
t=np.arange(0,20,dt)
BC=[3000,3000]
n=len(x)
m=len(t)
P=np.zeros((n,m))
P[0,:]=BC[0]
P[-1,:]=BC[0]
#theta=[0, 0.5, 1]
array_2=np.matrix([3000,3000,3000,3000])
IC=np.matrix(array_2)
print(IC)
for j in range(1,m):
    for i in range(1,n):
        P[:,0]=IC
       # sum1[i,j]=Act_diag[i,j] - theta*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j])
        #sum2[i,j]=(1- theta)*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]) + Act_diag[i,j]
        P[i,j]=((Act_diag[i,j] - 0.5*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]))/((1- 0.5)*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]) + Act_diag[i,j]))*P[i,j] + Q[i]/((1- 0.5)*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]) + Act_diag[i,j]) 
            
print(P)
```

Comment: You should add the error message here.

Comment: Yes, as @Phoenix says, you should put the full error message in your question, including the stack trace if there was one.  Also, it might matter how `Act_diag` and `T_tr` are defined, and you don't show us that.  What are those?  Can you provide definitions for that that would allow us to run your code?  Oh...and a definition for `Q` as well.  In short, you would have the best chance of getting a useful answer if you provided a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: here is the error message:                                                                    sum1=Act_diag[i,j] - theta*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j])

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Comment: Put those comments in the question itself - so they are easy to read!

Comment: Most likely you are trying to multiply a list by a number.  You can multiply an array by a number, but '*' for a list is different, it just means replicate, and only works with an integer.  `theta=[0, 0.5, 1]` - `theta` is a list!

Comment: . I also removed sum1 and sum2 and wrote one full equation for P.                                                                                                           
 P[i,j]=((Act_diag[i,j] - 0.5*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]))/((1- 0.5)*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]) + Act_diag[i,j]))*P[i,j] + Q[i]/((1- 0.5)*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]) + Act_diag[i,j]) 
            
print(P)

Comment: now, I'm getting another error saying :''C:\Users\hanab\OneDrive\Desktop\Numerical simulation\HW#4\HW4.py:239: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  P[i,j]=((Act_diag[i,j] - 0.5*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]))/((1- 0.5)*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]) + Act_diag[i,j]))*P[i,j] + Q[i]/((1- 0.5)*(T_tr[i,j]+J[i,j]) + Act_diag[i,j])